# How to define blank string in .ts file?

Tags: xml, qt, resources, translation

I need to define blank string in my translation file. Or at least whitespace. Is it possible?
I have tried `&#160; &nbsp; &#xa0;` etc. It does not help.

UPD. I have tried more different spaces. And have found that symbol "Zero Width Non Joiner" - `&#8204;` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Zero Width Non Joiner" - `&#8204;`